# Selenium webdriver not recognized as webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

So I have this `test` and `fixture`:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def init_driver():
    return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=TestParams.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH)


@pytest.mark.usefixtures('init_driver')
def test_1():
    driver = init_driver
    login(driver)
```

In this case my driver `type` is `<class 'function'>` so I cannot use its function for example get and got this `error`:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

When I change it to this:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('init_driver')
def test_1():
    login(webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=TestParams.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH))
```

My driver `type` is `<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="4ca3cb8f5bcec7a7498a65bfe5a2ea81")>`

And all works fine.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the syntax and changed it so that it runs without your hidden methods and variables such as login() and TestParams:

```py
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver

@pytest.fixture()
def init_driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

def test_1(init_driver):
    driver = init_driver
    print(type(driver))
```

Running that prints:

```
<class 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver'>
```

Comment: Still the same result

Comment: I just updated it to use `def test_1(init_driver):` , now it should be correct.